# Can I access Windows host details from inside a Virtual Box Ubuntu host?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, license-key

I have an application running inside an Ubuntu VM and I need to validate that it's running on only a specific computer (Windows host). Can I somehow get info from it (such as a Mac Address or a unique identifier for Windows) by configuring VirtualBox a certain way or running a script?

Comment: Not sure I understand clearly. Do you want your Ubuntu application find out if it is running on a specific virtual machine hosted under Windows?

Comment: No, I want to check if the Windows installation is the one that the key was activated on. So the application that's running inside the Ubuntu VM needs access to `wmic` so it can get a UUID or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Guest Additions installed [(link)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows), you might be able to use [Guest properties](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-guestprops) - I guess you'd set a property from the host, and verify it in the guest.

Comment: Can I set these from the commandline?

Comment: yes, the linked doc has samples